# Keras LSTM fit underfitting

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, lstm

I have time series training data of about 5000 numbers. For each 100 numbers, I am trying to predict the 101st. At the end of the series, I would put in the predicted numbers back into the model to predict ahead of the time series.
[image]
The attached graph shows the training data, the test data and the prediction output. Currently, the model seems to be under-fitting. I would like to know what hyperparameters should be changed, or if I need to re-structure my input and output data.

I am using the following LSTM network.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=([bl,1]), activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(20,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer=adam(lr=0.0001), loss='mean_squared_error', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(y_ba_tr_in, y_ba_tr_out,
          epochs=20,
          batch_size=5,shuffle=False,verbose=2)
```

y_ba_tr_in.shape = (4961, 100, 1)

y_ba_tr_out.shape = (4961, 1)

Comment: Why do you think you are underfitting? (IMHO, this will never work.)

Comment: Try reducing the amount of dropout if you're on the underfitting side. Some hyperparameter exploration such as increasing the state space size might help too.

Comment: Reducing the dropout didn't work. I'm not sure underfitting is the problem. I think one of the main problems is that I want a pattern output from a pattern input as opposed to just a single value for a pattern input. I may redo this for a time series output from a time series input.

Answer (score 0):

Something you could try is taking `return_sequences=True` out of your last LSTM layer. I believe this is generally the approach when you intend to predict for the next timestep.

After that modification, you also shouldn't need the subsequent `Flatten()` and `Dense()` layers.